# Why is this function printing an x instead of 1?

Tags: c++

I have written a small program for run length encoding.

```
void runLengthEncoding (string& str)
{
    int k=0;
    int count =1;
    for (unsigned i=1, count=1; i<str.size(); ++i)
    {
            if ( str[i] == str[k])
            {
                    count +=1;
            }
            else
            {
                    str[++k] = count+'0';
                    str[++k] = str[i];
                    count = 1;
            }
    }
    str[++k] = count + '0';

    str.resize(k);
}
```

When I call this function using

```
string s = "wwwwaaadexxxxxx";
runLengthEncoding (s);
cout << endl << s;
```

It is printing - `"w4a3d1e1x"`
It should print - `"w4a3d1e1x6"`

My doubt is why it is not printing the last count?

Comment: I don't understand your doubt.

Comment: Run under a debugger, run on breakpoint until the last loop, single-step, watch what is happening.

Comment: 'It should print "w4a3d1e11"' - no, shouldn't it print "w4a3d1e1x6"?

Comment: " It should print - "w4a3d1e11"" - really? Not w4a3d1e1x6 ?

Comment: I think you're going to run into some problems if a character is repeated more than 10 times.

Comment: Ideally it should print w4a3d1e1x6. But last else will not execute, as sson as string length over for loop will come out. that is another issue.

Comment: @vipw agree with you on that.

Comment: I think it is not a good idea to modify the input string. Your algorithm is suppose to perform run length encoding on a input string and generating a new string without modifying the original one.

Comment: You are resizing the string _after_ updating it! That can't be a good idea.

Comment: @TonyK we don't know the size of string in advance.

Comment: Oh, I just realised (thanks to Lahniep!) that you are modifying the _original string_. Not a good idea, and it will fail horribly if the run-length encoding is longer than the original (e.g. "bad_idea" becomes "b1a1d1_1i1d1e1a1").

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
str.resize(k)
```

i need to use

```
str.resize(k+1);
```

Comment: If you answer your own question then MARK IT as the answer (for future readers). Otherwise it's just a commentary and you as the question owner should just edit the question text to add the additional info.

Answer (score 0):

If you delete for count initialization, and resize correctly, you got it:

```
void runLengthEncoding (string& str)
{
    int k=0;
    int count =1;
    for (unsigned i=1; i<str.size(); ++i)
    {
        if ( str[i] == str[k])
        {
            count +=1;
        }
        else
        {
            str[++k] = count+'0';
            str[++k] = str[i];
            count = 1;
        }
    }

    str[++k] = count + '0';
    str.resize(++k);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. See my (second) comment to the OP.

Comment: Now try it on "bad_idea" , like I said in my comment.